# C++ Trying to compile the latest CE Kernel Driver results in Errors

Tags: c++, certificate, kernel, driver, signing

I'm trying to compile the most recent [cheat engine driver](https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine/tree/master/DBKKernel) but have had no luck so far.

I followed four different tutorials already and the driver should compile now. But I'm stuck on an error that is not mentioned in any of these tutorials, unlike many other errors.

The error is as follows:

> EXEC : error information: "CryptQueryObject" (-2147024893/0x80070003)

> EXEC : SignTool error : An unexpected internal error has occurred.

[image]

Searching for that specific error gives me 12 year old Google results that have never been solved or replied to, so I kinda don't know what to do now.

I've opened an issue post in that github and it got answered already with the following message:

> it's in the post build settings. You'll need to change it to your
> situation, or remove it and go with the driver signing tab instead. I
> switched to post build as my environment didn't support the new
> globalsign system anymore
>
> anyhow, it's a post build issue so the build was a success

I quite don't understand what to do, the reply seems a bit unclear to me.